# add an element "/" in particular position in string with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add an element "/" within a string, but only a specific position of it, e.g. from string "20180101" to expect result like "2018/01/01".is anyone know what syntax or how to make it happen.I'm still beginner in javascript

any help would be really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option using `replace` with a regex pattern:

```js
var input = "20180419";
console.log(input.replace( new RegExp("^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "gm"),"$1/$2/$3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `substr` approach to get the result:

```js
var str = "20180101";
str = str.substr(0, str.length-4) + '/' + str.substr(4, str.length);
str = str.substr(0, str.length-2) + '/' + str.substr(7, str.length);;

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option creating an array of sub-strings with `slice` (note that this would work the same way with `substring` here), and then joining each part with a `/`:

```
let s = "20180101"
let result = [s.substring(0,4), s.substring(4,6), s.substring(6,8)].join('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

*In such cases, you may find useful to treat your string as an array of digits.*

Get an array of digits from your string:

```
let myString = '20180101';
let myArray = myString.split('') //the '' splitter means it will just split anything
```

Then, add into your array of digits, the desired '/' digit in the desired positions. Refer to the splice method for more information.

```
myArray.splice(4,0,'/');
myArray.splice(7,0,'/');
```

Then, build your string:

```
myString = myArray.join(''); //the opposite of splitting
console.log(myString) // outputs '2018/01/01'
```